# How to project enum to id, value anon type?

Tags: c#, linq, enums, projection, anonymous-types

I have this enum:

```
  public enum Role {
    Admin,
    Manager,
    Engineer,
    User
  }
```

How could I project this into anonymous type, which I would send as JSON from a ASP.NET endpoint:

```
{
  { id: 0, name: "Admin" },
  { id: 1, name: "Manager" },
  { id: 2, name: "Engineer" },
  { id: 3, name: "User" }
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var result=Enum.GetNames(typeof(Role)).Select((e, i) => new { id = i, name = e });
```

`Enum.GetNames` return an `string[]` with the values of enum and `Select` extension method has an everload that gives you also the index

Comment: Possibly better to use `GetValues` and not assume the values are sequential integers starting at zero, something like `var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role)).Cast<Role>().Select(r => new { id = Convert.ChangeType(r, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Role))), name = r.ToString() });`.